# PHP variables inside HTML Code

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making a student sign-up form using html and php.

First you are asked to insert your name, password and email and when you click submit, it takes you to another page (`ChooseDepartment.php`) in which you get a list of all departments from my database to choose your own.

Now, I am a total newbie, so here is the part of my php code that I am stuck with in ChooseDepartment.php:

```
$ShowPossibleDep = mysql_query("SELECT NAME,DEPT_ID FROM DEPARTMENT");
if(mysql_num_rows($ShowPossibleDep) > 0){
    echo "<br />"."Available departments: "."  ".mysql_num_rows($ShowPossibleDep)."<br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo '<form id = "dept" action = "Courses.php" method = "post">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ShowPossibleDep))
    {
        echo $row['NAME'];
        echo '<input type="radio" name="department" value=<?php $row['DEPT_ID'] ?>>';
        echo "<br />";


    }
    echo '<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" id = "submitDepartment">';
    echo </form>;

}
```

I am trying to make the value of the radio button carry the value of the 
the department id so I can then update my  database with the student's department which is currently `NULL`, but I can't figure out how to use both html and php at the very same line correctly! This gives me syntax error!

Comment: I strongly believe you should read PHP in w3school first before start using SO. No pun intended.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is of very very low quality. It seems students as asking question to teacher in about basic syntax of a programming language

Comment: @Imdad: I think we should leave it open, as we all start from asking *low quality* questions. :)

Comment: Potatoes gonna potate! </3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you're in `PHP`, so you don't need to open and close `PHP tag`.

The reason you're getting *Syntax error* is just because you're not manipulating string properly.

error is with this line

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="department" value=<?php $row['DEPT_ID'] ?>>';              
                                                   ^ here                ^ here
```

So you need to remove the `PHP` tags and need to concatenate string properly like:

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="department" value="'.$row['DEPT_ID']. '">';
```

and with this one

```
echo </form>;
```

you're missing quotes around `form` tag. So it should be,

```
echo '</form>';
```

There are some other typos are as well, so your final code will be look like this.

```
$ShowPossibleDep = mysql_query("SELECT NAME,DEPT_ID FROM DEPARTMENT");
if(mysql_num_rows($ShowPossibleDep) > 0){
    echo "<br />Available departments: ".mysql_num_rows($ShowPossibleDep);
    //echo "<br />";  add this <br /> tag to next echo
    echo '<br /><form id = "dept" action = "Courses.php" method = "post">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ShowPossibleDep))
    {
        echo $row['NAME'];
        echo '<input type="radio" name="department" value=" '.$row['DEPT_ID'].'"><br />';
        //or you can do this way
        //echo "<input type='radio' name='department' value='$row[DEPT_ID]'><br />";
        //echo "<br />"; appended in upper statement.
    }
    echo '<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" id = "submitDepartment"></form>';
    //echo </form>;    closed already(above statement).

}
```

and without comments, more cleaner :)

```
$ShowPossibleDep = mysql_query("SELECT NAME,DEPT_ID FROM DEPARTMENT");
if(mysql_num_rows($ShowPossibleDep) > 0){
    echo "<br />Available departments: ".mysql_num_rows($ShowPossibleDep);
    echo '<br /><form id = "dept" action = "Courses.php" method = "post">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ShowPossibleDep))
    {
        echo $row['NAME'];
        echo '<input type="radio" name="department" value=" '.$row['DEPT_ID'].'"><br />';
    }
    echo '<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" id = "submitDepartment"></form>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to open php tag again

```
$ShowPossibleDep = mysql_query("SELECT NAME,DEPT_ID FROM DEPARTMENT");
if(mysql_num_rows($ShowPossibleDep) > 0) {
    echo "<br />"."Available departments: "."   ".mysql_num_rows($ShowPossibleDep)."<br />";
    echo "<br />";
    echo '<form id = "dept" action = "Courses.php" method = "post">';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ShowPossibleDep)) {
        echo $row['NAME'];
        echo '<input type="radio" name="department" value="' . $row['DEPT_ID'] .'">';
        echo "<br />";

    }
    echo '<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" id = "submitDepartment">';
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at string operators

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

You can combine two strings in php with a dot, so that part of your code would become this:

```
    {
        echo $row['NAME'];
        echo '<input type="radio" name="department" value="'.$row['DEPT_ID'].'">';
        echo "<br />";
    }
```